# Initializing an external variable sized array in C++

Tags: c++, llvm, xcode5.1, llvm5.1

I have a declaration like this:

```
extern "C++" CHARSET_INFO compiled_charsets[];
```

which compiled fine so far, but now with the update to XCode 5.1 I get an error for that:

```
.../my_sys.h:277:27: Definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer
```

It's certainly just a newly enabled LLVM check, but I'm curious to know how you would cope with such an error in general, especially if that is in a 3rd party header file you can't change. But also **if** you could change it what would it look like? I mean, how can I initialize an **external** array? It's defined somewhere else. It makes no sense to initialize the external reference.

Comment: The code is 100% legal, the bug is either in clang or in your environment. Are you seeing this error when compiling from the command line, or just from the IDE?

Comment: This is from within XCode 5.1.

Comment: Have you tried to compile from the command line?

Comment: That would not make any sense ,because 1) I need to use XCode. 2) The command line very likely uses the same compiler (I'd just compiling with the same toolset that XCode uses).

Comment: "That would not make any sense" --- I'm trying to diagnose the problem by eliminating the unknowns. XCode is one of the unknowns: no one is sure what exactly is going on inside. If you have other methods of troubleshooting in your toolbox, go ahead and try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Not sure why is LLVM having trouble with this but removing the "C++" part makes it compile that code again:

```
extern CHARSET_INFO compiled_charsets[];
```